# Jython console in Java Debug view for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jython

I am currently debugging a Java application (with the Eclipse IDE) and I would like to be able to run some "console" commands within eclipse while debugging.

I am familiar with python syntax and its compact code.

Therefore, I would like to be able to open a Jython console in the Eclipse IDE and to execute arbitrary code in it, with the current debug environment (while stoped at a breakpoint).

I know the "Watcher", but I don't find it really powerful or ergonomic.
Thanks.